# What does 'set up' mean in this sentence?

Tags: verbs

'Authorities are reporting a spike in thefts of Tide, and in some cities they have set up task forces where the detergent is sold to track the number of bottles in stores'

Can we say its meaning is 'organize or plan something'?

Comment: That's certainly one meaning -- see [Collins sense 2](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/set-up) -- and probably the only sensible meaning here.

Answer (score 2):

*set up* is being used to mean *establish*. A task force is presumably some variety of organisational unit, and such a unit has been established to track thefts of Tide.